# mongodb c# select specific field

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Need some help creating a *generic* method for selecting fields by their name.

something like this:

```
T GetDocField<T>(string doc_Id, string fieldName)
```

The best I got is using **projection** which gives me the doc with only the wanted field seted:

```
 public T GetDocField<T>(string Doc_Id, string fieldName)
 {
    var value = DocCollection.Find(d => d.Id == Doc_Id)
               .Project<T>(Builders<Doc>.Projection
               .Include(new StringFieldDefinition<Doc>
               (fieldName))).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
```

*note:*
I'm using the new c# driver **(2.0)**

Thanks!!

Comment: If it's generic then why select by name and not by expression?

Comment: I have posted a new question about sub field selection. 
for the googlers out there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161104/mongodb-c-sharp-select-specific-field-dot-notation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do next:

```
public async Task<TValue> GetFieldValue<TEntity, TValue>(string id, Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> fieldExpression) where TEntity : IEntity
{
    var propertyValue = await collection
        .Find(d => d.Id == id)
        .Project(new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<TEntity>().Expression(fieldExpression))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return propertyValue;
}
```

and call it

```
var value = await GetFieldValue<Item, string>("111", x => x.Name);
```

Comment: This works perfect, but i wanted to go a little forward with this solution. 
I added an edit for the question ,

thanks again !

Comment: @AviPinhas It's considered bad practice here on SO to [append a new issue to an existing question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/). Please edit out that second issue and post it in a new question. Again, would be great for you and the SO community to accept the answer above if you found it useful but there is no obligation in doing so.

Comment: I have posted a new question for sub field selection. 
for googlers who are interested:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161104/mongodb-c-sharp-select-specific-field-dot-notation