# mongodb c# select specific field dot notation

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

In addition for my previous question:
[mongodb c# select specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143586/mongodb-c-sharp-select-specific-field).

I'm writing a *generic* method for selecting a specific field.

the requirements are:

1. Field can be of any type
2. Return type is T
3. Field can be inside a sub field
4. Field can be inside array items - in that case its OK to select the specific field of all the items in the array

for shorts, im looking for the "select" / dot notation capability.
**for example:**

the wanted method:

```
T GetFieldValue<T>(string id, string fieldName)
```

the document:

```
persons
{
  "id": "avi"
  "Freinds" : [
    {
      "Name" : "joni",
      "age" : "33"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "daniel",
      "age" : "27"
    }]
}
```

The goal is to call the method like this:

```
string[] myFriends = GetFieldValue<string[]>("avi", "Freinds.Name");
myFriends == ["joni","daniel"]
```

as far as i know, using **projection expression** with lambda is no good for items in array, 
I was thinking more **dot notation** way.

*note:*
I'm using the new c# driver **(2.0)**

Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see good approach with don notation in string, because it has more issues with collections than generic approach:

For example `Persion.Friends.Name`

1. Which element is array in this chain?
2. You should apply explicit conversion for collection elements (possible place of bugs)

Generic methods are more reliable in support and using:

```
var friends = await GetFieldValue<Person, Friend[]>("avi", x => x.Friends);
var names = friends.Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```